# how to save Application Exceptions or crashes for posting to server-iphone

Tags: iphone

Hii People :

i have to send the exceptions or crash logs to server when the application has any crash or issues,

The exception may be (blob of data / long string / human readable)

Any idea on how to get exception logs when application crashes or when encountering with errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're app is on the AppStore you can pull all crash logs from iTunes Connect. In ad-hoc mode you can use the PlCrashReporter library.

http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/
https://github.com/TheRealKerni/CrashReporterDemo

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xcode to copy crash logs off of the device. Look for the organizer in the window menu.